# CosmosDB - Is there a way to get MongoDB API RequestCharge

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

So, when using MongoDB API with C# driver against CosmosDB, can we somehow get `RequestCharge` from CosmosDB response for each query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, for anyone struggling with same thing, here is the solution.

Cosmos DB MongoDB API has dedicated command called: **getLastRequestStatistics**

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units

So, immediately after a real query is executed, one should trigger:

```
var result = this._db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument{{ "getLastRequestStatistics", 1 }});
```

And that will give actual response from Cosmos DB with real cost. Response looks like:

```
{
"_t" : "GetRequestStatisticsResponse", 
"ok" : 1, 
"CommandName" : "find", 
"RequestCharge" : 5.5499999999999998, 
"RequestDurationInMilliSeconds" : NumberLong(25) 
}
```

Comment: Self-answered questions _should_ be accepted if you are happy with them - that is helpful in its own right, since future readers will know it worked for you.

Comment: (Aside: when the personal pronoun "I" to refer to yourself, please always capitalise it. A lack of capitalisation here creates editing work for volunteers, and you have a lot of posts).

Comment: @halfer, do you know if this this approach will make another call to the server? And how could this result be impacted with a lot of concurrent requests to the database server happening at the same time, can you make sure the number returned is from YOUR last request or it may be the cost of someone else request that happened after yours and before your getLastRequestStatistics?

Comment: @lmcarreiro: that's a question for the author of this answer, but by luck they have signed in and seen your message. I hope they can help you.

Comment: It was meant to direct it to @deezg

Comment: @deezg, do you know the answer to the question in my previous comment?

Comment: @Imcarreiro not that i am aware of. the whole mongodb api rather poor so i pretty quickly just switched to documentdb completely.

Comment: The linked ref: article is written for Cosmos SQL API, not Cosmos Mongo API, so it's a bit of a red herring.